vscode launches wrong port # in default browser ASP.NET Core app
I have the following block in my ASP.Net Core Program.cs:
     serverOptions.Listen(IPAddress.IPv6Loopback , 44300, listenOptions =>
     {
         listenOptions.UseHttps("ubu.test.pfx", certApiKey);
         listenOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http2;
     }); });

and the compiled app correctly launches on 44300. Only problem is the web browser opens http://localhost:5001 when debugging from VS Code (or Codium). I have lifted the hood to peek at applicationhost.config, launchsettings.json, launch.json (seems to be VSCode-specific, not visible in VSCodium), and appsettings.development.json. These files are where I am supposed to put environment variables to trigger the URL where the browser is supposed to open, but it seems to stubbornly decide to go to :5001 on localhost. Any way to change its mind? I have done most of the suggestions in Where to specify localhost port in VS Code but so far no luck. Any tips or hints appreciated!

Hi, how do you run the application? If you run by ctrl+F5, pls check the launch.json .
